# how to connect node.js server from c# (.net 3.5)

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, sockets

I already run the code that is on codeplex (SocketIO4Net) but its in .Net 4.0; I tried to convert it to 3.5 : obviously faced issued and unable to do that. Please tell me some way so that I can connect from .Net 3.5. I am using winforms and not expert in sockets. I would be very thankful for your assistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SocketIO4Net doesn't support .Net less 4.0 see http://socketio4net.codeplex.com/ it use System.Threading.Tasks and the for .Net 4.0 or higher.

SocketIO4Net use WebSocket4Net library https://github.com/mdavid/WebSocket4Net and it supports versions for .Net 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0. You can use it directly or find other client.